# Insert in h2 database oracle mode not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-test

I am running a component test and writing the data to an h2 database in memory in Oracle mode. The problem is that when making the insertion below to load the data in the database it is not working. When searching the data in the bank, it displays the current date, as if it were just a sysdate.

`INSERT INTO AVAILABLE_EMAILS (ID, EMAIL, TYPE, DAT_CREATION) VALUES (1, 'mock@mock.com', 0, SYSDATE - (30/1440));`

`INSERT INTO AVAILABLE_EMAILS (ID, EMAIL, TYPE, DAT_CREATION) VALUES (2, 'mock_2@mock.com', 0, SYSDATE - (20/1440));`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Well what date were you expecting?

Comment: On the first insertion, I expected the current date and time minus 30 minutes, but only returns the current date and time, as if I were doing a sysdate

Comment: I read some similar situations, but no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use two databases at once, you should avoid usage of vendor-specific syntax.

You can use SQL Standard-compliant

```sql
LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

in recent versions of Oracle and H2.

H2 also supports some of legacy Oracle-specific datetime arithmetic operators, but result of integer division in H2 is an integer value, `30/1440=0`. You can use `30.0/1440` instead (in both databases), but it's better to avoid such calculation at all, standard syntax is more readable.